# Phishing: allow # in user provided redirect URL?

Tags: web-application, url-redirection

I am currently working on an application that requires authentication for some pages. In order to be nice to our users we provide the ability to specify a redirect url to which the user is returned after logging in.

In order to avoid the *open redirect vulnerability* we want to make sure this URL is internal.

Right now we do the following:

1. Disallow any strings with characters other than `a-z0-9/=._-`
2. Always prepend our full base url (`https://www.example.com/`) before the user provided content. So even if the user sends us `https://www.evil.com` and it wouldn't already be blocked by step 1 it will end up as `Location: https://www.example.com/https://www.evil.com`.

However due to required frontend functionality we would also like to include `#` as a whitelisted character in step 1.

An example would thus be:

`Location: https://www.example.com/totally-relative-url#magic-that-leads-to-external-redirect`.

Does this open up any possibilities for open redirects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` in a URI denotes a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This is not sent to the server, and therefore cannot be used to cause a redirect without client-side help.

It **should** be safe to send back to a user, I would be more concerned with the rest of the URL than with the fragment.

Comment: The fragment is sent to the server and thus back to the client since that is exactly the functionality we require. So the `client-side-help` is what I am afraid of :)

Any other concerns regarding the rest of the URL when using this scheme?

Comment: I mean that when the client is redirected to `www.example.com/stuff/#fragment`, the `#fragment` is not sent to the server handling `www.example.com` and therefore cannot trigger a HTTP redirect. It would take special client handling to issue a request based on the value of `fragment`, but nothing standard exists.